# java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin play console review

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I got this error when send my flutter app for review. What does mean this error? I don't use "device features" like a lock screen or something like that in my app and can't understand what to do with that and even what it means. In the video from the message, the app is running and all looks good
[image]

Here is my dependencies from pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.6
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
  bloc: ^8.1.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  logger: ^1.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.5
  auto_route: ^5.0.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  html: ^0.15.1
  easy_refresh: ^3.0.4+3
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  tuple: ^2.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  collection: ^1.16.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  cupertino_back_gesture: ^0.1.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  flutter_local_notifications: any
  alice: ^0.3.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.11
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.18
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.9
  path: ^1.8.2
  lottie: ^2.3.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.0
  in_app_purchase: ^3.1.5
  in_app_purchase_storekit: ^0.3.6+3
  in_app_purchase_platform_interface: ^1.3.3
  in_app_purchase_android: ^0.2.5+4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.2.1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  freezed: any
  json_serializable: ^6.4.0
  # hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  auto_route_generator: any
```